# Meaning of 僕のほど in this sentence

Tags: words

I know ほど means ‘degree’ or ‘extent’ and so 僕のほど might translate as ‘to my extent’ but I don’t see how that possible translation fits with the rest of the sentence’s meaning.

> 彼女が僕に対して持っている気持ちは、僕のほど強くないようだ。

My translation: The feelings she holds against me don’t seem to be that strong.

Comment: She seems to not feel the same way as I do about her?

Comment: Here に対して does not mean "against" but rather "about" or "regarding"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The way I read this, you shouldn't see it as 僕のほど with の as the 'possessive' like 僕の猫, but rather view の here as acting like a quasi-pronoun. Like "彼女の車は青い。僕のは黒い。"

> 僕の(気持ち)ほど強くないようだ

[ほど often follows a noun directly](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%EF%BD%9E%E3%81%BB%E3%81%A9) without a の outside of keigo, and I think this is one of those situations.

So you could read the sentence as:

> It seems that the feelings she has for me aren't as strong as mine.